# Is the participant a dependent variable?

Tags: feature-selection

I have a table where data is like this:

[link to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yqKi.png)

It shows the distance covered by the participants with a specific sex and diet.

My question is if the "Participants" are independent values?

Or they cannot be put into the category (dependent, independent).

My gut says that the participants are independent values because they can be chosen / influenced by the researchers, whereas the distance cannot be chosen by them.